# python argparse, search for specific file if option is omitted

Tags: python, file, default, argparse, optional-arguments

I have an argument for input file and its easy to handle it with argparse

```
parser.add_argument( '-al', nargs = 1, type = argparse.FileType( 'r' ),
                     dest = 'alphabet' )
```

This parameter is optional but if it is omitted I still need to get this input file by searching current directory. And if there is more than one or none file with .al extensions I will raise the error, otherwise open file I found.

```
#if no alphabet look for .al file in current directory
if( args.alphabet == None ):
    AlFiles = [ f for f in os.listdir( '.' ) 
                if os.path.isfile( f ) and f.endswith( '.al' ) ]

    #there should be one file with .al extension
    if( len( AlFiles ) != 1 ):
            sys.exit( 'error: no alphabet file provided and '
                    'there are more than one or no .al file in current directory, '
                    'which leads to ambiguity' )

    args.alphabet = open( AlFiles[0], 'r' )
```

Is there anyway to perform this with argparse, with default or action parameters maybe.
If I do the search before parsing arguments and there are an exception situation I still can not raise it because needed file may be provided by command line arguments. I thought of performing action if parser did not meet needed parameter, but can not find out how to do it with argparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that by setting the default attribute for the argument.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-al',
                    type = argparse.FileType('r'),
                    default = [ f for f in os.listdir( '.' )
                                if os.path.isfile( f ) and f.endswith( '.al' )],
                    dest = 'alphabet' )
```

And afterwards do your checking. That way you only have one function checking if there are more than one or none *.al files whether the argument was omitted or not.

This could, for example, be accomplished by something like this:

```
args =  parser.parse_args()
if isinstance(args.alphabet,types.ListType):
    if len(args.alphabet) != 1:
        parser.error("There must be exactly one alphabet in the directory")
    else:
        args.alphabet = open(args.alphabet[0])
```

This way args.alphabet will hold an open file if there was a alphabet file specified or there is only one alphabet file in the current working directory, but will raise an error if there are more or none in the cwd.

**Note**:
Because we get a list if the `-al` argument is omitted, `argparse.FileType('r')` will not open any file.
You also have to omit `nargs=1` since that would create a list containing the one opened file, the user specified in the `-al` argument. Omitting this attribute will give us the raw open file, the user specified.

**EDIT:** You will have to `import types`.

Comment: So after parsing i just checking `args.alphabet` for size?
And if there are several files they all will be open?

Comment: As I understand your question, you only want to open a file if it is the only *.al file in the directory. Check my edit for a solution attempt.

Comment: yah I got your answer, just in add_arguments type is FileType that means that all files are open automaticly

At least you should not reopen it again `args.alphabet = open(args.alphabet[0])`

And if several files open would they be close if we raise the error?

Comment: You are right, I missed that.
What do you exactly want to parse with the -al argument? The name of the .al file or the directory containing it?

Comment: I just want open one file thats all

Comment: I understand that. The question is: What does the user specify with the -al argument?
If the argument is not omitted, do you specify the folder containing the *.al file(s) or do you specify the path to the file like: path/to/file.al ?

Comment: No, user just pass the name or path to the file. and if it is omitted, than I seek current directory( not any other ) for that file with already hardcored extension.

Comment: I hope I could help you and my attempt solves your problem. I would very much appreciate if you accept my answer, should it work for you.
Thanks ;)